# Change a cell value in a sheet based on the value of another sheet cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets in a workbook, "Sheet1" and "Sheet2".

I want sheet2 cell A1 value to be either string "Potato" or "Tomoato" based on the cell value of A1 or A2 in sheet1 with a condition.

e.g.

```
if A1 (sheet1) >= 7 or A2 (sheet1) >= 7 then
    A1(sheet2) = "Potato"
Else 
    A1(sheet2) = "Tomato"
```

I already having code in sheet1.

```
Dim xVal, yVal As String

Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static xCount As Integer
    Static yCount As Integer
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Address = Range("C28").Address Then
        Worksheets("sheet2").Range("T3").Offset(xCount, 0).Value = xVal
        xCount = xCount + 1
    Else
        If xVal <> Range("C28").Value Then
         Worksheets("sheet2").Range("T3").Offset(xCount, 0).Value = xVal
        xCount = xCount + 1
        End If
    End If

    If Target.Address = Range("C24").Address Then
        Worksheets("sheet1").Range("U3").Offset(yCount, 0).Value = yVal
        yCount = yCount + 1
    Else
        If yVal <> Worksheets("Main").Range("C24").Value Then
            Worksheets("sheet1").Range("U3").Offset(yCount, 0).Value = yVal
            yCount = yCount + 1
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    xVal = Range("C28").Value
    yVal = Range("C24").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Help with what? How does the posted code relate to your question at the top?

Comment: Got the answer  Just add these lines of code in the end of subroutine Worksheet_change()

if Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").value >=7 or Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2").value >=7 then
Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A1").value="Potato"
else
Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A1").value="Tomato"
end if

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but if your target is:

> if A1 (sheet1) >= 7 then A1(sheet2) = "Potato" Else A1(sheet2) = "Tomato"

you don't need vba at all.
You just simply put in A1(sheet2) cell directly the IF function in this way:

=IF(Sheet1!A1>=7;"Potato";"Tomato")

and that's it :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i need VBA because A1(sheet2) is already handled by 2 functions (using buttons) which already calling these strings "Potato" and "Tomato" on different conditions. So if use IF statement then when i call these functions, the statement will be erased.